# How to use Facebook's Account Linking feature to verify that the messenger user is a registered user of my website?

Tags: php, laravel-5, facebook-messenger-bot

I need to check if the messenger user already has an existing account to my website before they can proceed to a certain action in the app.

In my website, a user can login via Facebook then after their first successful login, their facebook id is saved to the database. Now, the same user logs in to messenger and interacts with my bot, but the problem is, the ids returned by messenger and facebook are totally different although they are the same user.

I have read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/v2.9) but still, I can't fully understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have modified the code on glitch to support account_linking
please check : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/violet-pyramid?path=bot.js:20:0

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I was able to make it work by following your code. Now, my next question is how do I keep track of the user they use my app. For example, I have a quiz app on my messenger and I need to track the users progress with like how many question they already answered and keep track of their points. How do I use the authorization_code return from the account linking process to do it? Is it possible to save it to a session? Or do I need to set it as a payload in every request?

Comment: every webhook contains PSID (page scoped user id). You can store all the activity of a user against that id. Authorization code is only for security purpose. However, you can use to to map the PSID to your internal database userId or some unique user identifier. You can send the metadata about the question in th payload so that you can map which question was seen / answered by the user.

Comment: Do you mean that within the process of account linking, after I verified that the messenger user has an existing user account with my website, I will update his database record and add the PSID returned by messenger?

Comment: Yes. That should suffice for you to keep track of user's progress.

Comment: Thanks! Now it looks more clear to me. Can this also work for creating new user accounts on the website? How is the flow going to look like for creating new users?

Comment: yes this can be used to create new users on your site. In the account linking flow you can have "Sign up" / "Login with FB" button for new users and users can signup in the web-view which is opened in the account linking flow. I would suggest you should use login with fb as the user is already logged into fb and they will just have to click accept in the consent screen. Hope this help! Would love to see your bot in action :) Do share link if there is no privacy issues.

Comment: Still a long way to go but i will definitely share it to you as soon as it is ready. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for and was introduced with Messenger Platform v2.0:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was able follow this process easily and now I am able to get the user's facebook id. My next problem is how do I keep track of user as they interact with my app? Can I save it in a session?